# Bayes theorem - is it applicable in any case?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayes-theorem

I'm studying the Bayes' Theorem and I have a doubt. In [this wikipedia page](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) there's an example of application for the following events:

```
A = probability of raining on Sunday
B = probability of raining on Monday
```

but with the following example:

```
Suppose we have a marble bag with 3 red marbles and 2 blue marbles
A = probability of getting a blue marble first
B = probability of getting a blue marble second
```

I can calculate P(A and B) = P(B|A) * P(A).

My question is: does it make sense to say, for Bayes' theorem, that

P(A and B) = P(A|B) * P(B) ?

P(A|B) seems temporally illogical.. and P(B) seems impossible to calculate with a fixed value (since it depends on A).

Where am I getting wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm used to definining $P(A|B)$ as $P(A \cap B)/P(B)$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Definition

Comment: The probability of $B$ is not only can be calculated, it is obviously $\frac{2}{5}$. Imagine the balls to have ID numbers etched on them. Any ball is just as likely to be drawn second as to be drawn first, all permutations are equally likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we don't distinguish between the different marbles of the same color, then in our experiment we have four possible outcomes: RR,RU,UR,UU. (I use "U" for blue to avoid confusing it with the event $B$). Conditioning on the event you're calling $B$ amounts to assuming that the second outcome is U, that is, restricting attention to the second and fourth outcomes, and updating the distribution accordingly.

Bayes' rule and the total probability formula are the main tools here. For instance you mention that the distribution of the second draw depends on the outcome of the first draw. But that doesn't mean that you can't calculate $P(B)$, it just means you have to consider all the possibilities leading into the second draw in order to calculate $P(B)$. Specifically, you get a red with probability $3/5$, in which case you have probability $1/2$ to get a blue the second time; or you get a blue with probability $2/5$, in which case you have probability $1/4$ to get a blue the second time. So $P(B)=\frac{3}{5} \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{5} \frac{1}{4} = \frac{8}{20} = \frac{2}{5}$.

(Here I assume from context that the draws are without replacement.)

Comment: oh, and isn't P(A|B) illogical? Isn't it the probability of drawing a blue marble at first round given that a blue marble was extracted at second round (??)

Comment: @Albert It makes sense. Thinking about it in terms of time is confusing you. Look at my first paragraph. The *entire experiment* has four outcomes, which have probabilities 6/20,6/20,6/20,2/20 respectively. When you assume $B$ happened, you assume that either the second or fourth outcome happened. So the probability of RU becomes $\frac{\frac{6}{20}}{\frac{8}{20}} = \frac{3}{4}$ while the probability of UU becomes $\frac{\frac{2}{20}}{\frac{8}{20}} = \frac{1}{4}$. It is important here to think about the entire experiment as one unit, not as two completely separate experiments.

Comment: Thanks Ian, I got that I need to think of a probability problem not as something "happening and being created" but as a mathematical tree of events where I exclude or include rows.

Comment: @Albert A nice example to really test your understanding is the "medical test" example. You have a big population of people. A known small fraction of them have an illness. You have a test for this illness, which has known nonzero rates of false positives and false negatives. Say that $A$ is the event of a person having the illness and $B$ is the event of a positive test. Here $P(A|B)$ is a very important quantity: it measures how confident are we that someone who tested positive actually has the illness. Note that it has the same "temporal" problem as your example.

Comment: @Albert (Cont.) You can compute $P(A|B)$ using Bayes' rule, given the numbers that I've said were known, i.e. $P(A),P(B|A),P(B|A^c)$. What you find is counter to our intuition: even if $P(B|A)$ is quite large and $P(B|A^c)$ is quite small, if $P(A)$ is quite small then $P(A|B)$ is not very large at all.

Comment: @Albert (Cont.) This example shows where your concern becomes important in practical problems: $P(A|B)$ is not directly measurable, because there is no way to run the experiment only on those individuals with a positive test. Instead it has to be *inferred* from other information. Bayes' rule is the tool for the job.